# Chrome does not see attributes redefined with getter and setter added with Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, getter-setter

I need to redefine Getter and Setter on an element of a web page (let's say an "iframe"), for the "src" property. 
Here is the code:

```
this._targets = {
        "document.createElement": {
            capture: true,
            funcName: "createElement", 
            obj: document, 
            origPtr: document.createElement
        }
 };

_MycreateElement = function() {
var target = this._targets["document.createElement"];
var elem = target.origPtr.apply(target.obj, arguments);

if(arguments[0] == "iframe"){
    Object.defineProperty(elem, "src", {
        get: function() {
            var _src = src;
            console.log(_src);

            return _src;
        },
        set: function(value){
            _src = value;
        }
    });
}
return elem;
}
```

_MycreateElement is an overloaded function on the normal "createElement" and the overloading works correctly.
The problem is that Chrome seems to create like a "shadow src" and works with his own. (I can read and write my _src variable but Chrome doesn not use it.)

I found out that it works adding `this.getAttribute('src')` and `this.setAttribute("src", value)` but this is not what I need.

Does anyone have some ideas?

I was thinking to "unbind" the overload function, get/set the value and "rebind" it. Do you think is it possible?
How can I restore (temporarily) the normal getter/setter?

Comment: That's just horrid, what's wrong with creating an element and setting the source the regular way, it's like two lines of code ?

Comment: I need to overload the setter and getter method in such a way that, when the src property of an element is modified, I can check it. I don't want to set the src with a specific value, I need to control it, every modification of that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the only way to solve my problem was to use `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`.
I really think it's the only way to do that!
To completely reach the goal of my problem (that was to "keep an eye" on how the `src` property of an element was changing) I needed to redefine the `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` functions, for each element, as well.